# How to get to page1 when I refresh my gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in my webform.

In my search I got to page 4 for example, now I need to refresh the gridview and go to page 1.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upon the postback assign the GridView.PageIndex property to 0

```
mygridView.PageIndex = 0;
```

Have a look at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You update a [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) but changing the `DataSource`, after this you need to call [`DataBind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) on the GridView. And you can use [`SetPageIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.setpageindex.aspx) to change page. Which will also trigger the `OnPageIndexChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the PageIndex value

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindex.aspx

Comment: Assigning -1 will raise a ArgumentOutOfRangeException